# .net core, run the default angular template in docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to run the default angular template from .NET Core 3.1 as a docker instance.

I already read on different pages ([also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812316/how-to-dockerize-dotnet-core-angular-template-application)) that adding the following should be enough.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
```

But I still get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmp859332ce906f4bcaad00b1b144b3fec4.exec.cmd: npm: not found
/src/Internationaal-Dashboard/Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj(42,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish "Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Somebody any clue what I am forgetting.

I will include the full docker file below:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Internationaal-Dashboard/Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj", "Internationaal-Dashboard/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Internationaal-Dashboard/Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Internationaal-Dashboard"
RUN dotnet build "Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Internationaal-Dashboard.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Internationaal-Dashboard.dll"]
```

Comment: Try adding `npm` to the `apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs` line? I don't know nodesource but in ubuntu it's in a separate package I think.

Comment: I tried it, but no sucess with adding npm. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.